# WP8 Map in a Panorama

Tags: dictionary, windows-phone

I have a Map control within my Panorama application.

Since the map is scrollable, it stops the  user from swiping to the next screen. The purpose of the map is to capture the user's location and allow the user to move the map around slightly.

Once the user is satisfied with the positioning of the map, I wish to allow the user to swipe to the next screen but this becomes difficult as the map is almost fits in the entire width.

Code:

```
     <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Location">
            <maps:Map x:Name="Map" ZoomLevel="7"/>
     </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the user is satisfied with the position you can set `IsHitTestVisible` to false on the `Map` control.

```cs
Map.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

This will prevent scrolling to affect the map control and your panorama will respond to scroll events instead.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Any idea how I can make the Panorama App slide to the other screen upon a button click?

Comment: I think I answered this on your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899938/wp8-automatic-slide-to-next-screen